# Get rid of virus that downloads apk

Tags: factory-reset, apk, antivirus

My android tablet, a zoom, has started to download apk's at random without any initiation on my part. I have the don't allow foreign apk's to be installed thing checked so they can't get on to the tablet. Has anyone else caught this? I don't see anything else on the internet about it and I have done a search with Avast to no avail at finding anything.

I suppose that the easiest way to remove it is factory reset. If I do that does google remember all my apps and download them instantly?

Anyway any I'm grateful for any information.

Comment: Are you sure that they aren't the updates to the app you've already installed?

Comment: Yes, I have no app for hot girls uk installed. I can click the apk, it doesn't install but briefly boots. Pretty sure they are viruses.

Comment: Care to provide the logcat?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/taVrXCEb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Backup & reset. Then check 'Backup my data' and 'Automatic restore'. 
An alternative is to use an app like Ultimate Backup or Titanium.

Answer (score -1):

the Google does not saves your apps.
I have tryed that.
I was downloaded 380 mobile security and it detected 40 viruses.
I pressed clean all and a rescaned:
The viruses wasn't removed.
I performed a factory reset and the viruses was removed.
This is the solution when you have many viruses on android.
My tablet model is:Maxwell maxtab H10